# what is the best way to know when all submitted tasks has been finished by Executor Service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

here is two options , just bit confuse which one is best to go.

**Option 1:**

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<Runnable> tasks = getTasks();
CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = tasks.stream()
                               .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, es))
                               .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();    
es.shutdown();
```

**Option 2:**

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List< Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for(Runnable task : taskList) {
    futures.add(es.submit(task));
}

for(Future<?> future : futures) {
    try {
        future.get();
    }catch(Exception e){
        // do logging and nothing else
    }
}
es.shutdown();
```

Here putting future.get(); in try catch is good idea right?

Comment: The first one is better, it clearly shows that you are waiting all tasks finished.

Comment: same thing is happening in second one also , there i am waiting till all tasks completed and there i have option to put in try-catch too to handle any exception. there is know way to do the same in first approach

Comment: So basically you want to whether all the futures are done executing?

Comment: yes , i need to move to do next level of processing once all tasks completes

Comment: @user2862544 The second way can achieve it. But it seems a little bit obscure. The others who read this code might think why call `get` and did not pick the result? Although you can add some comment to explain it is used for joining all runnables.

Comment: in future.get() i don't need result , i just want to know when all tasks getting completed, in option 1 what will happen if any exception occurred in between. considering this whats your thought now.

Comment: Do you want a blocking or non-blocking operation for checking?

Comment: it should be blocking right ? as i mentioned that  i need to move to do next level of processing only if once all tasks completes

Comment: The actual implementation of the checking methods needs not to be blocking. You can block the flow of the program elsewhere. Shall I go ahead and post an answer?

Comment: yes please, it would be great if go with my example

Comment: @user2862544 check below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to wait for all tasks to complete. After you submitted all of your tasks, call

```
es.shutdown()
es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANO_SECONDS)
```

[Oracle's Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) read:

> **shutdown** [...] Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed.
>
> **awaitTermination** [...] Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Concerning the timeout: with the above values, the thread-pool will only terminate after about 300 years.

Comment: I think this one is best as i only need to know when my tasks are getting completed so that i can move for next processing. but shutdown should not cancel any pending tasks. for example if i am submitting 5k tasks(task max will take 10 mili seconds) to pool of 10 threads than all should get finished.@Aris_Kortex please provide your thoughts

Comment: Please mark my answer as the best one if it's sufficient. If your comment as a question: Shutdown doesn't terminate any tasks, it just prevents the executor from accepting any more tasks.

Comment: this answer is quite good but still falls victim of unnecessary exception handling. Furthermore defining an arbitrary termination may lead to unexpected results e.g a blocked task may get the whole thread stuck until the termination threshold has been reached. Ideally if this approach is to be followed a two step termination process should be followed  Finally just for the purposes of polling the various task states and since you already cache the futures in a list I would go with the simplest possible way of determining whether they have finished.

Answer (score 3):

Since you effectively hold each submitted `Future` in a list of of futures by doing this:

```
List< Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for(Runnable task : taskList) {
    futures.add(es.submit(task));
}
```

You can very easily check if all the submitted jobs are done executing just, by invoking the `Future#isDone` method, which wilkl return true or false based on whether the task has finished or not. You can check  more on this on the related documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()).

Hence, with the above in mind you could very well create a simple helper method, that will iterate the list of your futures and check on their state. For example:

```
private boolean areJobsDone() {
    return futures.stream()
        .allMatch(Future::isDone);
}
```

Note that in contrast to the `Future#get` method, `isDone` is non blocking (as it's not waiting for the task to return it's result) as it effectively queries it's state.

With this you can go ahead and check for the state of your runnables, blocking the flow with a loop that will invoke the helper method, before proceeding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you mean to say use something like below:  while(!areJobsDone()){ }

Comment: @user2862544 Yes something like that.

Comment: what adavantage we will get here over get() method and inside while(!areJobsDone()){ }  there is nothing to do? does it make sense?

Comment: @user2862544 I did not get what you mean by your last comment. Can you clarify a bit please?

Comment: invoking get will result in blocking until you get the actual task result. with the solution mentioned above you avoid that. furthermore this way you avoid dealing with exception handling. Also you'll not have a misleading bit of code (i.e s get that effectively does nothing). Finally you could very easily expose the state if your executor service outside the bounds of this class quite easily. Invoking and polling this method should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the Aris_Kortex' proposal,

```
List<CompletableFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for(Runnable task : taskList) {
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, es));
}
```

and then create the combined CompletableFuture:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(futires.size()));
```

then you can wait for all tasks synchronously:

```
cf.get();
```

synchronously with timeout:

```
cf.get(1, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```

of asynchronously:

```
cf.thenRun(()->{finalActions();});
```

Comment: I think @Nearoo one is best as i only need to know when my tasks are getting completed so that i can move for next processing. but shutdown should not cancel any pending tasks. for example if i am submitting 5k tasks(task max will take 10 mili seconds) to pool of 10 threads than all should get finished. please provide your thoughts